# Why does an infinite loop not run in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, infinite-loop

So im trying to have a function run in 4 separate instances using the `multiprocessing` module. Inside the function is an infinite loop but for some reason it only runs one time and returns control of my terminal window to me.

Here are the 2 functions:

The function that creates the pool

```
def mainLogic():
    global direction_array

    pool = Pool()
    for dir in direction_array:
        pool.apply_async(generic_arrow_logic, args=(dir, direction_array.index(dir)))
        print("starting process " + str(direction_array.index(dir)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The function that im trying to run infinitely

```
def generic_arrow_logic(arrType, thread):
    #Average runtime = .3 seconds so roughly 3fps
    
    global color_dictionary, key_dictionary, arrowArrayCurr, default_arrow_color
    last_time = time.time()
    parseCoords(False)

    while True:

        working = screenGrab("not") #numpy array of entire image
        currArr = cutImage(working, arrType, "not")#.convert("RGB") - Another numpy array
        (height, width, depth) = currArr.shape
        print("Loop on process {0} took {1} seconds...".format(thread,time.time()-last_time))
        last_time = time.time()

        if(not (currArr[int(width/2), int(height/2)] == default_arrow_color).all()):
            pydirectinput.press(key_dictionary[arrType])
        # sys.stdout.flush()
```

and this is what happens when I run the program

```
starting process 0
starting process 1
starting process 2
starting process 3
Loop on process 0 took 0.02699136734008789 seconds...
Loop on process 2 took 0.04453277587890625 seconds...
Loop on process 1 took 0.060872793197631836 seconds...
Loop on process 3 took 0.07178044319152832 seconds...

Jalen Morgan@gridl0ck-TL MINGW64 ~
$
```

Does anything stand out in my code that would explain why this doesn't run forever?

Comment: I don't immediately see anything obvious. It could be dying with an exception. I seem to recall exceptions getting suppressed in some scenarios while multiprocessing. Pepper the `generic_arrow_logic` loop with `print`s and see if you can narrow down where it's dying. Or try doing a catch-all `try` and manually printing out the caught exception.

Comment: Python supresses exceptions in the worker and raises them in the parent when you get the the async result... but since you don't save and check the return from `apply_async`, exceptions are silently discarded. I think you have an exception in the worker and just don't see it.

Comment: The fix depends on how you want to handle exceptions. Should the entire process shut down? Should the single worker terminate, or perhaps just that round in the loop?